# Simplest REST service not working

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, .net-4.0

Can anybody tell me why is this REST service not working?

```
namespace WCFRestExample
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class HelloWorld : IHelloWorld
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="/", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "HIIII";
        }
    }
}

namespace WCFRestExample
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorld
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData();
    }
}
```

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am able to browse the service .svc and I get the page correctly but when I browse:

```
http://localhost:60503/HelloWorld.svc/GetData
```

I get a 404 page. Can anybody tell me what is happening and where can I find tutorials for WCF REST? This is the simplest service one could create and even that is not working for me.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: is there wsdl for REST? No, at least by default, as far as I know. And this is obviously not highly customized solution :)

Comment: @Tom Squires: WSDLs are for SOAP services not Http based REST services. Seems you too are new to this ;)

Comment: show content of svc file, you might have configured ServiceFactory incorrectly.

Comment: @Int3: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WCFRestExample.HelloWorld" CodeBehind="HelloWorld.svc.cs" %>

Comment: That is not suffient, you also need to provide servicefactory

Comment: After adding `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"` Now I get different error: `[InvalidOperationException: Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not defining anywhere that this should be a REST service - neither do you have an endpoint in your web.config that uses the `webHttpBinding`, nor did you specify in your `*.svc` file to use the `WebServiceHostFactory`.

The simplest fix would be to fix the svc file to:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
      Service="WCFRestExample.HelloWorld" CodeBehind="HelloWorld.svc.cs"
       Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

With this, your svc file now defines it wants to use the `WebServiceHost` (the host that understand REST) to host your service...

Check out [An Introduction To RESTful Services With WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx) for a great intro to REST services with WCF.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your URI template to:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/GetData", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

**Update**

The bit in the uri template can be anything, so it can be:

```
/GetMySuperComplicatedData
```

and still be mapped to *GetData()*

For more information read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx

Comment: Tried adding a trailing slash to the end of getData? so /GetData/ thats on the request and on the uri template

Answer (score 1):

try `http://localhost:60503/HelloWorld`, and show us your `Global.asax`

Comment: I tried. Still getting 404 error. There is no global.asax in project. Should I add one? What should I write in that?

Comment: Did you use WCF 4.0 project template when creating the project? It is not a standard one, but you can download it (`File -> New Project -> Online Templates -> WCF -> WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)`). It will create a project with a lot of common configuration done for you, including `global.asax`. Take a look there, it is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

It could be one reason that you did not set ServiceHostFactory properly

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#"       
                Service="WCFRestExample.HelloWorld"  
                CodeBehind="HelloWorld.svc.cs"    
                Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
%>
```